# supports Rtl doesnt work on devices 5.1 like nexus 4 or galaxy 4 with res-layout-large

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I develop application with many activities that need to work in rtl mode.

In my manifest I add

```
android:supportsRtl="true".
```

And in my activity I had this code :

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE);
    }
```

It's work almost all the screens.

In 2 activities I work with some layout sizes : `layout-large` and `layout-large-hdpi`.

When the application is running, these 2 activities show all the layout at ltr.

When I remove this layouts from the large folders, it works fine.

The wierd issue is that it occurs only on devices that work with 5.1 OS, when I run  on Galaxy 2(4.0.3) it's work fine.

Does anyone knows what is this bug or run into this problem ?

**UPDATE:**

I found that if i reduce the targetMinSDk to 16 it's not happen but it's occurs to another problems(like set action bar in left..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I run on gradle file against buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'.

When I upgrade to buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' it's works perfectly.

It's seem that it's was bug in buildTools 23.0.0 with RTL.